# Jquery gauge to coordinates

Tags: jquery, gauge

I am developing a project for college where I control the position of two motors using a MVC 3 application.

I'm looking for some component or something that allows me to show the user the current position of the motor angle (0, 15, 36, and ...)

Does anyone have any solution as searched and found nothing similar

Exemple:

[image]

Comment: Look in to HTML5 canvas http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: This solution this Jquery-Knob http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try jqChart's Radial Gauge: http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/RadialGauge/Scale

Disclaimer: I work for jqChart.